# What to send to front end after successful authorization of token on server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

My flow on front end is login page -> profile page

On the back I get the token from header like so:

```
app.use(verifyToken);

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path === '/auth/google') {
        next();
    }
    else {
        var token = req.headers.authorization;
        client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: token,
            audience: 'myClientId'
        }).then(pay => {
            res.status(200); // What to send here?
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(401).json({error: err});
        });
    }
}
```

So the login page calls `/auth/google` which verifies the token above and then redirects to `/profile` page where another API call is made...except the second API call is not being called. It works if the token verification function is removed above. So I need a `next()` somewhere to keep things going?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Never mind, I switched out the `res.status(200)` with `next()` which continued fired the API call on the profile page.